# JQuery/DOM element "click" event registration: on("click") VS click() VS addeventlistener("click")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm learning javascript, and I've seen more than one way of registering click events:

```
$(DOMelement).click(function() {});
$(DOMelement).on('click',function() {});
(DOMelement).addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

Can someone tell me what's the best practice for event registration? Or the major advantage/disadvantage of each one? I'm asuming on() and click() are very similar, but since I'm just getting started I would like to know which is the most used so I can start writing efficient code from the start. Also, is it still a good practice to do the html onclick registration?

```
<button onclick="function()"></button>
```

Comment: `$(DOMelement).addEventListener` isn't a function. `addEventListener` is a native DOM Element function and you must unwrap the element from jQuery to use it: `$(DOMelement)[index].addEventListener`

Comment: You should try to keep your javascript out of your HTML as a general rule of thumb, and the three registrations are essentially the same. #3 is not jQuery, but used correctly it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: So should I be using the addEventListener over the first ones?

Comment: So basically you are asking what is the difference between jQuery and native DOM? Or whether you should use jQuery or not? *"is it still a good practice to do the html onclick registration"* I don't think it ever was good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(DOMelement).click(function() {});` is the shortcut of `$(DOMelement).on('click',function() {});`. It's a little bit less character, but `$(DOMelement).on('click',function() {});` is faster.

`$(DOMelement).addEventListener('click', function() {});` will never work because it is a native JavaScript function. You need to use an HTML element, not a jQuery one. That would work :

```
$(DOMelement)[0].addEventListener'click', function() {});
```

This is the fastest one because it is native, but there is [some support issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent), like in IE 8 and lower, it will throw an error because it use `.attachEvent()`.

You last solution (`<button onclick="function()"></button>`) is the worst possible solution since it is bad for re-utilisability, make a lot of repetition when you have multiple element and also is a bad practice.

Basically, you should always use (when jQuery is loaded) `.on()`.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9, and above, implement `addEventListener()` (check the compatibility: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)).

Comment: @sgarcia performance wise, yes! Also, `.on()` can [be used for event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 0):

These two use jQuery to bind the event to a callback and are an alias of the same exact function (`.on`):

```
$(DOMelement).click(function() {});
$(DOMelement).on('click',function() {});
```

This one uses the browser's api to bind it (a little lower level):

```
DOMelement.addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

The last one also works similar to the browser api way but it frowned upon:

```
<button onclick="function()"></button>
```